# Unreachable statement in line StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer()

Tags: java, android

The error is:

```
Unreachable statement in line StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer()
```

Here is my code:

```
    public void viewAll(){
    btnViewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cursor res =myDB.getAllData();
            if (res.getCount() == 0)
                showMessage("Error","No data Found");
            {
                return;
            }

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            while (res.moveToNext()){
                buffer.append("Id :"+res.getString(0)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Name :"+res.getString(1)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Surname :"+res.getString(2)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Marks :"+res.getString(3)+"\n\n");

            }
            showMessage("Data",buffer.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your code.You have used the {} at wrong position thats why your facing this issue.

```
if (res.getCount() == 0){
            //show message
            showMessage("Error","No data Found");
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced the starting curly brace of if statement. Return is called always and lines below return are never executed. Hence unreachable statement..
Add the curly braces as below

```
            if (res.getCount() == 0){
                //show message
                showMessage("Error","No data Found");

                return;
            }
```

The above code will fix the issue. But, a better approach will be to avoid the unnecessary return statement. Like this :

```
public void viewAll(){
    btnViewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Cursor res =myDB.getAllData();
          if (res.getCount() > 0){

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            while (res.moveToNext()){
                buffer.append("Id :"+res.getString(0)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Name :"+res.getString(1)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Surname :"+res.getString(2)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Marks :"+res.getString(3)+"\n\n");
            }
            //show all data
            showMessage("Data",buffer.toString());
          }
          else{
             //show message
             showMessage("Error","No data Found");
          }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Always use the pattern "Return first" avoiding many layers of code.